# Accessing Google Storage with SparkR on bdutil deployed cluster

Tags: r, apache-spark, google-hadoop

I've been using bdutil for a year now, with hadoop and spark and this is quite perfect!
Now I've got a little problem trying to get SparkR to work with Google Storage as HDFS.

Here is my setup :
- bdutil 1.2.1
- I have deployed a cluster with 1 master and 1 worker with Spark 1.3.0 installed
- Installed R and SparkR on both master and worker

When I run SparkR on master node, I'm trying to point a directory on my GS bucket serveral ways:

1) By setting the gs Filesystem scheme

```
> file <- textFile(sc, "gs://xxxxx/dir/")
> count(file)
15/05/27 12:02:02 WARN LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
15/05/27 12:02:02 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/05/27 12:02:02 WARN LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
collect on 5 failed with java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.SparkRBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(SparkRBackendHandler.scala:111)
        at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.SparkRBackendHandler.channelRead0(SparkRBackendHandler.scala:58)
        at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.SparkRBackendHandler.channelRead0(SparkRBackendHandler.scala:19)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1383)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
        at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.BaseRRDD.getPartitions(RRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1511)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:813)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:312)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.collect(JavaRDD.scala:32)
        ... 25 more
Error: returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE
```

2) With a HDFS URL

```
> file <- textFile(sc, "hdfs://hadoop-stage-m:8020/dir/")
> count(file)
collect on 10 failed with java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.SparkRBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(SparkRBackendHandler.scala:111)
        at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.SparkRBackendHandler.channelRead0(SparkRBackendHandler.scala:58)
        at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.SparkRBackendHandler.channelRead0(SparkRBackendHandler.scala:19)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://hadoop-stage-m:8020/dir
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
        at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.BaseRRDD.getPartitions(RRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1511)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:813)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:312)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.collect(JavaRDD.scala:32)
        ... 25 more
Error: returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE
```

3) With a path as I would use with Scala on my other Spark jobs : quite the same error as 2)

I'm sure I'm missing an obvious step. If there is anyone who can help me on this matter, it would be great!

Thanks,

PS: I'm 100% sure that gcs connector is working on a classic Scala job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You need core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, etc., and the gcs-connector-1.3.3-hadoop1.jar on your classpath. Accomplish this with:

```
export YARN_CONF_DIR=/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/conf:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/lib/gcs-connector-1.3.3-hadoop1.jar
./sparkR
```

You may also want other `spark-env.sh` settings; consider additionally running:

```
source /home/hadoop/spark-install/conf/spark-env.sh
```

Before `./sparkR`. If you're calling sparkR.init manually in R, then this isn't as necessary since you'll pass params like `master` directly.

Other possible pitfalls:

1. Make sure your default Java is Java 7. If it's Java 6, run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and select Java 7 as default.
2. When building sparkR make sure to set Spark version: `SPARK_VERSION=1.3.0 ./install-dev.sh`

**Long Answer**

Generally, the "No FileSystem for scheme" error means we need to make sure core-site.xml is on the classpath; a second error I ran into after fixing the classpath was "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem" which means we also need to add gcs-connector-1.3.3.jar to the classpath. Looking through the SparkR helper scripts, the main `sparkR` binary calls `sparkR.init` with the following:

```
  sc <- sparkR.init(Sys.getenv("MASTER", unset = ""))
```

The `MASTER` environment variable is commonly found in the `spark-env.sh` script, and indeed `bdutil` populates the `MASTER` environment variable under `/home/hadoop/spark-install/conf/spark-env.sh`. Typically, this should indicate that simply adding `source /home/hadoop/spark-install/conf/spark-env.sh` should sufficiently populate the necessary settings for SparkR, but if we peek inside the `sparkR` definition, we see this:

```
#' Initialize a new Spark Context.
#'
#' This function initializes a new SparkContext.
#'
#' @param master The Spark master URL.
#' @param appName Application name to register with cluster manager
#' @param sparkHome Spark Home directory
#' @param sparkEnvir Named list of environment variables to set on worker nodes.
#' @param sparkExecutorEnv Named list of environment variables to be used when launching executors.
#' @param sparkJars Character string vector of jar files to pass to the worker nodes.
#' @param sparkRLibDir The path where R is installed on the worker nodes.
#' @param sparkRBackendPort The port to use for SparkR JVM Backend.
#' @export
#' @examples
#'\dontrun{
#' sc <- sparkR.init("local[2]", "SparkR", "/home/spark")
#' sc <- sparkR.init("local[2]", "SparkR", "/home/spark",
#'                  list(spark.executor.memory="1g"))
#' sc <- sparkR.init("yarn-client", "SparkR", "/home/spark",
#'                  list(spark.executor.memory="1g"),
#'                  list(LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/directory of JVM libraries (libjvm.so) on workers/"),
#'                  c("jarfile1.jar","jarfile2.jar"))
#'}

sparkR.init <- function(
  master = "",
  appName = "SparkR",
  sparkHome = Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),
  sparkEnvir = list(),
  sparkExecutorEnv = list(),
  sparkJars = "",
  sparkRLibDir = "") {

  <...>
  cp <- paste0(jars, collapse = collapseChar)

  yarn_conf_dir <- Sys.getenv("YARN_CONF_DIR", "")
  if (yarn_conf_dir != "") {
    cp <- paste(cp, yarn_conf_dir, sep = ":")
  }
  <...>

    if (Sys.getenv("SPARKR_USE_SPARK_SUBMIT", "") == "") {
      launchBackend(classPath = cp,
                    mainClass = "edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.SparkRBackend",
                    args = path,
                    javaOpts = paste("-Xmx", sparkMem, sep = ""))
    } else {
      # TODO: We should deprecate sparkJars and ask users to add it to the
      # command line (using --jars) which is picked up by SparkSubmit
      launchBackendSparkSubmit(
          mainClass = "edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.SparkRBackend",
          args = path,
          appJar = .sparkREnv$assemblyJarPath,
          sparkHome = sparkHome,
          sparkSubmitOpts = Sys.getenv("SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS", ""))
    }
```

This tells us three things:

1. The default `sparkR` script fails to pass `sparkJars`, so there doesn't appear to be a current convenient way to pass libjars as flags.
2. There's a TODO to deprecate the `sparkJars` param anyways.
3. Aside from the `sparkJars` param, the only other thing going into the `cp`/`classPath` argument is `YARN_CONF_DIR` (unless I'm missing some other source of classpath additions, or if I'm using a different version of sparkR than you). Also, fortunately, it appears to use `YARN_CONF_DIR` even if you're not planning to run on YARN.

In all, this shows you probably want at least the variables in `/home/hadoop/spark-install/conf/spark-env.sh` since at least some of the hooks appear to look for environment variables commonly defined there, and secondly we should be able to hack `YARN_CONF_DIR` to specify both the classpath to make it find core-site.xml as well as to add gcs-connector-1.3.3.jar to the classpath.

So, the answer to your question is:

```
export YARN_CONF_DIR=/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/conf:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/lib/gcs-connector-1.3.3-hadoop1.jar
./sparkR
```

You may need to change the `/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/lib/gcs-connector-1.3.3-hadoop1.jar` part if you're using hadoop2 or some other gcs-connector version. That command fixes both the HDFS access as well as finding the `fs.gs.impl` for the gcs-connector as well as making sure the actual gcs-connector jar is on the classpath. It doesn't pull in `spark-env.sh` so you might find it defaulting to running with `MASTER=local`. You may consider running the following, assuming your worker nodes have also properly installed SparkR:

```
source /home/hadoop/spark-install/conf/spark-env.sh
export YARN_CONF_DIR=/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/conf:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/lib/gcs-connector-1.3.3-hadoop1.jar
./sparkR
```

A couple additional caveats based on what I encountered:

1. You may find your R installation set an older Java version. If you run into something like "unsupported major.minor version 51.0", run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and make Java 7 the default.
2. If you're using Spark 1.3.0, if you're using SparkR's `install-dev.sh`, Spark may erroneously hang with "Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory" when in fact dispatchers are fast-failing with serialVersionUID mismatches, which you can see in /hadoop/spark/logs/*Master*.out - the solution is to make sure you run install-dev.sh with the right Spark version set: `SPARK_VERSION=1.3.0 ./install-dev.sh`

Comment: @DennisHou can you post the TODO for the sparkJars deprecate? is it on the spark or sparkR jira?

Comment: Also, if sparkR.init is being called manually in R then 'YARN_CONF_DIR' can be set within in R like 'Sys.setenv(YARN_CONF_DIR="/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/conf:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/lib/gcs-connector-1.3.3-hadoop1.jar")' before starting sparkR.init. 'sparkJars' is used to pass jar files to the worker nodes, not sure why it is to be deprecated, is there an alternative way to pass jar files manually in R?

Comment: Ah, for the TODO I just meant the comment I saw here: https://github.com/amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg/blob/master/pkg/R/sparkR.R#L126 - I don't actually know if it's an official TODO. The deprecation says that they'll favor simply using "--jars" instead to be picked up by SparkSubmit:

      # TODO: We should deprecate sparkJars and ask users to add it to the
      # command line (using --jars) which is picked up by SparkSubmit

Comment: IIRC that would translate to the config key `spark.jars` in the manual-invocation case.